# JBoss ignores Main-Class and Start-Class attributes declared in MANIFEST.MF of war application

Tags: spring-boot, jboss7.x, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have an issue with a Spring Boot 2 WAR application deployed on a JBoss EAP 7.2 instance.

The server ignores the "Main-Class" and "Start-Class" "attributes declared in the MANIFEST.MF of my built war application, which has multiple main classes inherited from an external war dependency.

The war is generated with spring-boot-maven-plugin, which produces a MANIFEST.MF like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: WEB-INF/classpath.idx
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: myuser
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: WEB-INF/layers.idx
Start-Class: the.application.path.AppRunner
Spring-Boot-Classes: WEB-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: WEB-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.5.2
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_272
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

This is the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>the.application.path.AppRunner</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
         <execution>
              <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
               </goals>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The generated war seems fine even in the content, but in the server.log of JBoss I have the following messages:

```
2021-11-02 22:10:08,125 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) 7 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2021-11-02 22:10:08,718 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) 
2021-11-02 22:10:08,718 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-11-02 22:10:08,718 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-11-02 22:10:08,718 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-11-02 22:10:08,718 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-11-02 22:10:08,719 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-11-02 22:10:08,719 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-11-02 22:10:08,719 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)
2021-11-02 22:10:08,720 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) 
2021-11-02 22:10:08,849 INFO  [another.path.AnotherRunner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Starting AnotherRunner on 9737e3eb4c40 with PID 79 (started by jboss in /home/jboss)
```

As you can see, it's trying to start a different main class instead of what I want.
Then the server tries even to launch every Spring Boot main class included in the war.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is another.path.AnotherRunner from your war or is it a library? If so, which library?

Comment: @jordiburgos is from the "parent" war application. My app extends the original one.

Comment: JBoss EAP would not execute any `Main-Class` manifest entry. That is a Java SE entry and not used in Jakarta EE at all. This is likely something to do with Spring Boot.